# Looking for open source LGBT datasets

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, csv, lgbt

I have been looking for any general datasets about LGBT Americans. The type of file I look for are either CSV or TSV. Although my inquiry will hopefully yield some spatial indices at the county or state level, because of the apparent lack of initial success in searching I am hoping for data of some depth of any sort.  Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what type of LGBT data you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a lot of good nation-wide data on LGBT topics. Here are a few I was able to find for you. Some of them are already in CSV/TSV and/or Excel format (and therefore trivial to convert to CSV) while some are PDF reports with tables embedded (which, given some effort, could be converted to CSV/TSV tables):

- XLS Census/ACS data on same-sex couples: http://www.census.gov/hhes/samesex/data/acs.html
- CSV data: "Project to scrape and analyze the data from the Municipal Equality Index, which is a 2013 report from the Human Rights Campaign which rated 292 municipalities on their LGBT policies." - https://github.com/Radcliffe/MunicipalEqualityIndex
- PDF report w/ data: "Sexual Orientation and Health Among U.S. Adults:
  National Health Interview Survey, 2013" - http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nhsr/nhsr077.pdf
- PDF report w/ data: "Same-sex Couples and the Gay, Lesbian, Bisexual Population: New Estimates from the American Community Survey" - http://williamsinstitute.law.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/Gates-Same-Sex-Couples-GLB-Pop-ACS-Oct-2006.pdf
- A website with links to other LGBT data in varying formats and levels of granularity: http://www.lgbtdata.com/

Comment: Thank you for answering such a general question.  I am using data to create a portfolio and I didn't need anything specific.  The github link is especially nice because it has a spatial dimension.

Comment: If you were to go further as far as process in trying to find more data, especially spatial data, where would you start?

Comment: @StephenEngley - I would search more on lgbtdata.com and look at HRC's data and try to get more from them.