# Individual-level data (e.g. survey) with information on sexual orientation

Tags: data-request, survey, lgbt

I am looking for data on the individual-level that contains information on the sexual orientation (or a reasonable correlate thereof). I would ideally like a data set like  from the [DHS program](http://www.dhsprogram.com) or the [WV-Survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/wvs.jsp), so that it contains biographic or other answers to survey questions.

*Clarification*: I am not looking for a dataset of LGBT individuals, but for a dataset with an indicator for sexual orientation. Obviously it would be okay if non-hetero individuals were oversampled, given that I want to run statistics pertaining to them, but I still need all kinds of respondents in there.

Comment: Please be aware that I already found http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/looking-for-open-source-lgbt-datasets/6964#6964 , but it is not satisfactory

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything else I could clarify

Answer (score 2):

Pew Research has a dataset that was used for this article:

**[A survey of LGBT Americans](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2013/06/13/a-survey-of-lgbt-americans/)**

You can download the data [here](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/category/datasets/?download=19799), after registering.

Survey information:

> Findings in this report are based on two main data sources:
>
> This report is based primarily on a Pew Research Center survey of the LGBT population conducted April 11-29, 2013, among a nationally representative sample of 1,197 self-identified lesbian, gay, bisexual and transgender adults 18 years of age or older. The sample comprised 398 gay men, 277 lesbians, 479 bisexuals and 43 transgender adults. The survey questionnaire was written by the Pew Research Center and administered by the GfK Group using KnowledgePanel, its nationally representative online research panel.
>
> ...
>
> In most cases the comparisons made between LGBT adults and the general public are taken from other Pew Research Center surveys.

---

*Please note that I find your question vague and the comment about not being a duplicate doesn't explain why. If you add more details to the question, I think that would help.*

Comment: Thank you. I will clarify my question. In short: I'm looking for data with an indicator for sexual orientation, **not** data from an exclusively LGBT sample.